# jobs -l is not printing output to a file when written inside a script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, file, jobs

I want output of “jobs -l“ written to a file and the jobs -l command is written inside a shell script program

“jobs -l“ command works when simply given in terminal even it prints to file “jobs -l >file.txt“ when simply given in the terminal but not inside a program.

### ./program.sh

```
jobs-l >file.txt
```

### file.txt

```
[1]+  3693 Running                 firefox &
```

this is the expected output inside a file

but actually, I am getting nothing inside the file. the file is created but it's empty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because you are starting a new shell within the script.
This shell has indeed not a running background process.

You can try it with starting firefox in your current shell: `firefox &` and opening another shell and run this command: `jobs -l`.
This should be empty.

If you would start your firefox background process in your script it would show up.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

firefox &
jobs -l > processes
```

Comment: Thank you,this was great help